# Chez Cosette suspendue pour cause d'inactivité

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

La salle de clavardage peut-elle être réinstaurée, ou est-elle figée pour le restant de l'éternité?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'ai dégelé la salle. (Seuls les modérateurs peuvent le faire, mais ça peut être n'importe quel modérateur sur tout Stack Exchange, parce que le clavardage est partagé entre les sites.)

Une salle de clavardage est gelée s'il n'y a aucun message pendant 14 jours, hors message par des bots (“feeds”).

[Le système protège la dernière salle associée à un site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130472/dont-freeze-a-chatroom-soon-after-a-mod-has-unfrozen-it/130504#130504), mais sans s'occuper de savoir si c'est la salle principale. Je crois qu'il y a eu une série de salles de courtes durées consacrées à des prolongations de commentaires sur des questions en particulier, et en parallèle la salle principale est vide ces temps-ci.